# ArrayList comparing and get shared Values

Tags: java, arraylist

I am breaking my mind to find a solution to the following problem.
I have 4 different ArrayList that get their values from a Database.
They can have size from 0 (including) till what ever.
Each list may have different size and values also.
What I am trying to do effectively is :
Compare all the non 0 size lists and check if they have some common integers and what are those values.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a collection of common integers for all, excluding empty ones:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = ...
Collection<Integer> common = new HashSet<Integer>(lists.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < lists.size(); i++) {
   if (!lists.get(i).isEmpty()) 
     common.retainAll(lists.get(i));
}
```

at the end the `common` will contain integers that common for all of them.

Comment: Will this work if one of the lists is empty? Because if it is empty I still need to know if there are common values to the rest of the lists that are not.

Comment: What do you need - common integers that are in all lists, or a set of integers, where each one is common for at least for two of them?

Comment: Just only the integers that are common for all the lists that have values.If they dont have values there is no need to be compared between them.For example if 3 of the lists have values I want to know if there is a common value in 3 of them and what is this value.

Comment: @natix Try to compile this code before downvoting. It works. Though, I altered the code as I agree, that having a collection of them is better.

Comment: @Eugene Retunsky: I don't see how a fact that a code can be compiled is an argument. Arrays of generic types are just bad and in this case also unnecessary. Nevertheless, the altered code is now OK, so I cancelled my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You might be wanting to use apache commons [`CollectionUtils.intersection()`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) to get the intersection of two collections...

Iteratively generate the intersection, and if it is not empty when you are done - you have a common element, and it is in this resulting collection.

Regarding empty lists: just check if its `size()` is 0, and if it is - skip this list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set intersection operations with your ArrayList objects.

Something like this:

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

l1.add(1);
l1.add(2);
l1.add(3);

List<Integer> l2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
l2.add(4);
l2.add(2);
l2.add(3);

List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(l2);
l3.retainAll(l1);
```

Now, l3 should have only common elements between l1 and l2.

Comment: With 2 lists seems easy! Now what if there are 4 and we dont know witch has values or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. If you have multiple elements to search, put the search in a loop.

List aList = new ArrayList();
aList.add(new Integer(1));

if(aList !=null && !aList.isEmpty()) {
   if(aList.contains(1)) {
      System.out.println("got it");
  }
}